# Can I Unlock The Fallout: New Vegas Steam Achievements If I Buy It Through Bethesda.Net?

Tags: steam, achievements, fallout-new-vegas

Fallout: New Vegas Ultimate Edition is currently 50% off on the Bethesda.net launcher.

If I buy it there, can I just add it to my Steam account and earn the Steam achievements for Fallout: New Vegas, or do the achievements only work if I get a Steam key for the game?

When buying/installing the game, no option for Steam was shown, and I did not get a key to activate it on Steam. It seems that I can only play it through the Bethesda.net launcher, so I am thinking about refunding it, unless someone else knows a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have made contact with Bethesda customer support, and sadly, only the newer games (Skyrim and onward) give you a Steam key. Linking accounts only works for the Online games, like Fallout 76.

So to get a Steam key, I have to refund my copy from Bethesda.net, and buy it again on Steam.

Answer (score 9):

According to [Bethesda's FAQ](https://help.bethesda.net/app/answers/detail/a_id/34177/%7E/how-do-i-buy-something-on-bethesda.net%3F), you are purchasing a key to activate the game via Steam.

> "Pease note that a **Steam account** is required to activate any game key purchased on Bethesda.net.

However, you have confirmed this was not the case. You'll have to get in touch with technical support to either correct or refund it.